# Unable to send external email via crontab

Tags: email, cron, ssmtp

I'm trying to send email out from crontab. I've tried making crontab run a basic shell script, as well as specifying the actual command within the crontab. I've tried doing this with mpack and ssmtp . I've noticed that if i execute the command or shell script in a terminal, it works fine. It only fails when i try to schedule it.

This is the basic essence of the command i need to run, where im emailing abc@abc.com the contents of a file. The file is generated daily and is named after the year, month, and day.

```
echo -e "to: abc@abc.com\nsubject: abc123\n" | ssmtp abc@abc.com < `date +%y%m%d`.txt
```

Similar thing with mpack

```
mpack -s "abc123" `date +%y%m%d`.txt abc@abc.com
```

I've figured that it has something to do with the date variable. If i substitute that with the actual name of the file, then it all works fine. I've made sure to escape the % symbol, and have tried replacing the backtick with $(date +%y%m%d) with no luck.

Crontab looks like this

```
10 10 * * * /home/user/./script.sh
```

Also tried this method

```
10 10 * * * echo -e "to: abc@abc.com\nsubject: abc123\n" | ssmtp abc@abc.com < `date +\%y\%m\%d`.txt
```

I've made sure that the shell script includes #!/bin/sh, checked all file permissions, and changed the environmental path to include the directories for ssmtp and mpack.

Any suggestions why the date variable is making this fail? Do i need to escape anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify full path to binaries and file.

Your `script.sh` should look like this :

```
#!/bin/sh    
/path/to/echo -e "to: abc@abc.com\nsubject: abc123\n" | /path/to/ssmtp abc@abc.com < /path/to/`date +%y%m%d`.txt
```

Then your Crontab should be like this :

```
10 10 * * * /home/user/script.sh
```

(assuming your script has the x bit `chmod +x`)